# TypeScript: Implicit cast from any to everything?

Tags: typescript

I'm just learning TypeScript and I'm a bit perplexed about the nature of `any`. Take a look at this:

```
var x: any = 1;
var y = 1;
x = y;
y = x; // why does this not cause a compile-time error?
```

At first I understood `any` to be the type without any promises - which is why the first assignment is reasonable to work - but it appears that in other contexts (the second assignment), it can be a type with *all conceivable* promises.

For example, this piece of insanity also compiles just fine:

```
undefined.foo
```

That's because `undefined` is assumed to be `any`, which is a type promising everything. Hmmm.

Contrast this to

```
var a : HTMLElement = new HTMLDivElement();
var b = new HTMLDivElement();
a = b;
b = a; // doesn't compile. phew.
```

Here we get what I would expect from assigning a more general thing to a more special thing in a strongly typed language: An error, as an explicit cast would be necessary:

```
b = <HTMLDivElement>a; // ah, you mean it's really a div...
```

In most cases where `any` is used, I would expect something like `unknown`, defined as

```
interface unknown { }
```

would be a better choice.

I first came across this problem as my code was using `eval` to parse json. `eval` returns `any`, which means that TypeScript thinks that you can do everything with it, without any casts.

I think that's clearly wrong. Compare that issue to factories in other typed languages, such as C#:

```
(MyType)Activator.Create(typeof(MyType)) // cast is needed
```

Or C++:

```
// cast is needed in C++ (not in C, though I think it really should...)
(MyType*)malloc(size);
```

Whenever I have a function that produces something untyped, I would expect that I need to cast it before I can use it for anything.

So my questions are:

1. Is there the analogous to `any`, something like the above `unknown`, that is standard?
2. If so, why is `any` featured so prominently and the other so hidden?
3. Has this issue been raised somewhere? Is there a discussion anyone can link to?

Comment: With TypeScript 3.0, there is an 'unknown' type now: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type

Answer (score 10):

To the first question, the equivalent to `unknown` is `{}`, the empty type. The compiler will sometimes produce `{}` when no other type can be computed (for example, in `['foo', 42]`, the element type was `{}` before it became `string|number` with the addition of union types).

Next, the reason `any` is often mentioned is that the typical complaint about TypeScript is that it has *too much* type enforcement, rather than too little. JavaScript programmers just don't seem to be in to writing typecasts all the time. Obviously this is a matter of taste, but it is what it is.

This is all very much by design because a core scenario for TypeScript is to take an existing piece of JavaScript and add exactly as much type information as you want without getting tons and tons and tons of errors. Whenever TypeScript sees something without a type annotation where its type can't be inferred, it's going to use `any` because that's the type that lets the most JavaScript compile without errors.

The `undefined.foo` thing was fixed in version 1.1. It now correctly reports an error (the exact treatment of `undefined` and `null` in TypeScript is an interesting but separate discussion).

As Steve mentions, `noImplicitAny` is there to help. It will raise errors when something is of type `any` where there wasn't an explicit type annotation.

Answer (score 8):

The `any` type is a special type. Where possible, you should avoid using the `any` type unless you want to take advantage of dynamic types.

The `any` type is a short way of saying...

> Treat this variable as if it were compatible with *any* other type.

So you can assign it to a string, a number, an array, an object, a interface with any structure... anything at all.

So don't think of it as being an `any` type, think of it as being "a *string* if I assign it to a *string*".

You can avoid accidental use of the `any` type by passing the `--noImplicitAny` compiler flag (or setting your project settings to use this flag).

Comment: Thanks for `--noImplicitAny`. That helps in practice. (For other VS users: You can switch that on in the project options in the "TypeScript Build" tab.)